# Cannot convert value of type '(String, JSON)' to expected argument type '[JSONSubscriptType]'

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am attempting to loop through a set of posts and getting their media by looping through the counts of images.

This doesn't work - `images` being set to `0`

```
for images in JSON(response.value!)["post"]["media"] {
    print(JSON(response.value!)["post"]["media"][images]["image_url"])
}
```

But this does

```
for images in JSON(response.value!)["post"]["media"] {
    print(JSON(response.value!)["post"]["media"][0]["image_url"])
}
```

The error I get is

```
Cannot convert value of type '(String, JSON)' to expected argument type '[JSONSubscriptType]'
```

It appears that usinga variable from the loop won't work, but a direct Int does. I've also tried wrapping `images` as an `Int`

Answer (score 0):

The working code reveals that the object for key `media` is an array of dictionaries.

So in the loop `images` (actually `image`) represents one item of the array `media` in each iteration.

Assuming `JSON` is related to `SwiftyJSON` – which has become obsolete in favor of `Codable` by the way – you have to write

```
for image in JSON(response.value!)["post"]["media"].arrayValue {
    print(image["image_url"])
}
```